# How can I disable URL Activities shortcuts in KDE Plasma 5?

Tags: arch-linux, plasma5

This window appears when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on URL address, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Common Keyboard Shortcuts in KDE](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/fundamentals/kbd.html)

Read [Keyboard shortcuts - Perform common Firefox tasks quickly](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly)

Comment: This window also appears when i want copy path in dolphin. However when i turn off klipper in tray, then problem disappears. I use Vivaldi browser.